# How to run ansible playbook with current date's inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have inventory file generated on daily basis and I want to run my ansible playbook by choosing current date's inventory file.

Could someone help me on how to provide the ansible command to achieve my target?

It should be something like below

```
ansible-playbook run_repo.yml -u user1 -i my-instance-(mm-dd-yyyy).yml
```

Comment: What's your date format?

Comment: its (mm-dd-yyyy) @Styszma

Comment: Assuming you're using bash following should work: ansible-playbook run_repo.yml -u user1 -i my-instance-$(date +%m-%d-%Y).yml

Comment: I've added this as an answer that you can approve, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using bash following [date formatting](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/) should work:

```
ansible-playbook run_repo.yml -u user1 -i my-instance-$(date +%m-%d-%Y).yml
```

Comment: what if I use ```ansiblePlaybook ()``` command to run the same playbook with the current date with the given format?

Comment: this is my playbook command
```ansiblePlaybook (playbook: 'run-repo.yml', inventory: 'my-instances-ips-${date +%m-%d-%Y}.log', installation: 'ansible-latest')``` .. its not working actually.. i am passing this command in my jenkins pipeline.

Comment: I believe that Jenkins Ansible plugin might not parse bash functions. If you would use script instead that should work.